# c# template function fails float CompareTo double

Tags: c#

I tried to make generic function to compare two elements T and U but it fails to work with float and double.

```
public static bool Fun<T, U>(T a, U b) where T : IComparable { 
    return a.CompareTo(b) > 0; 
}
```

As I figured it boils down to one problem.

If I use
`var c = Comparer<double>.Default;`
Then I can compare, for example, `c.Compare(3.1f, 2.1)`.

But if I use
`var c = Comparer<float>.Default;`
Then comparison `c.Compare(3.1f, 2.1)` fails (as well as `3.1f.CompareTo(2.1)`) with

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'

Is there a generic way to deal with that properly?
Using comparison `3.1f < 2.1`will definitely work, but I want to make it work for any two `IComparable<T>` and `IComparable<U>`.

For example, could we decide the most common class between T and U?
If T is float and U is double, then it would use U for `comparer<U>`.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: "It fails" - How? Do you not get the expected result? Do you get an exception? Compilation error?

Comment: c.Compare(3.1, 2.1f)
(1,11): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'

Comment: basically, the question might be reformulated:
Is there c# analogue of  std::common_type?

Comment: You might have to take a different approach in C# vs C++. The double to float conversion is failing because it's a downcast & may result in loss of information. If you would actually post the function you have and the calling code, it would be much easier to give you some guidance. Looking at code is easier than talking about it.

Comment: public static bool Fun<T, U>(T a, U b) where T : IComparable
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) > 0;
        }

Comment: I cannot add breaklines here :(

Comment: No, there is no way to do that properly (as in, efficiently) for any combination of `T` and `U`, barring some exciting dynamic code generation. C# generics are not C++ templates. The "most common class" between `double` and `float` would be `object`, so that's no help. `IComparable<T>` is only for comparing between `T`s.

Comment: Its recommended to edit your question to add additional information that was requested in comments. This also allows you to format the code properly. I have done that for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid it wouldn't be straightforward, so the bitter truth confirmed. That means, making more functions specifically for int, float, double combination or go for dynamic

Comment: And thanks to Georg for editing, I'll try to follow the guidance next time. Not yet experienced with writing nice style messages in the web

Comment: The closest thing C# has to this is the fact that the built-in `operator<` can do cross-type comparisons via conversions, and even user operator overloads consider implicit conversions (which is why you can compare a `float` to a `double`), and expression trees are a thing. That is, `Expression<Func<double, float, bool>> c = (double d, float f) => d < f;` compiles and gives you an expression tree that includes the necessary conversion. This may or may not be useful -- this stuff can get hairy rather quickly. (Like C++ templates, really.)